# Primereact dropdown stopped working after React 17 upgrade

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, primereact

I'm using a dropdown component from Primereact(v1.6.2). After upgrading the react from 16.3 to 17.0.2, I see almost all the Primereact controls are working but dropdown. When I try to open the dropdown, it didn't even open the menu for selection. I tried to upgrade the prime react, as well but themes and modules in the latest version of it impacts the application UI completely. Please share your thoughts if any.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Most likely this is fixed in a later PrimeReact and your old 1.6.2 version does not support React 17.  Upgrading to PrimeReact 6 might be your only solution.